# Google App Engine Modules :Confused about routing (dispatch.yaml)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dispatch

[After digging into the problem, it seems the issue is not about the routing but about the use of endpoints in modules. New question at [GAE Modules and Google Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135252/gae-modules-and-google-endpoints])

I'm migrating an GAE application to modules, and I'm confused about the routing, as some queries are correctly routed, but not all of them.

I have the following dispatch.yaml in my root folder. Note that that api module is using the Google Cloud Enpoints API

```
application: testapp

dispatch:
  - url: "*/foo/*"
    module: foomodule
  - url: "*/_ah/spi/*"
    module: api
  - url: "testapp.appspot.com/"
    module: default
```

And then one folder by module name, each with a yaml file, defining the URL patterns with handlers, e.g. /www/www.yaml for my default module

```
application: testapp
version: alpha
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: www.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

Queries such as http://testapp.appspot.com/xxx are correctly redirected to default, /foo/xxx ones are handled by the foomodule, but API requests (/_ah/spi/xxx) are going to the default module with a 404.

**However, I can see a 200 OK for /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages in the logs of the instance mapped to the api module.** This one comes from alpha-dot-api-dot-testapp.appspot.com - while the 404 are from testapp.appspot.com only. (NB: I'd like to make my queries work from testapp.appspot.com)

Is there something I am doing wrong? Also, is there a way to list the configuration currently used on the server to make sure it's correctly deployed?

Comment: Do you have a `- url: /_ah/spi/` handler in your api yaml file?

Comment: Yes, I have handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: myapi.app

Comment: Have you run: `appcfg.py update dispatch.yaml www.yaml api.yaml foo.yaml`? And, in api.yaml, does it have `module: api`?  Do you have any open instances running on the api module?  If so, they have have stale code - kill them and try again.

Comment: @GAEfan - yes I have the module reference in api/api.yamp. I've already run appcfg.py update www/www.yaml upload/upload.yaml api/api.yaml ; appcfg.py update_dispatch . But still the same error. Even after killing the instances. Also have the 404 when calling the API from the API console / explorer.

Answer (score 2):

It is tempting to factor out endpoints api into a separate module and use dispatch.yaml to set up routes but with dev_appserver.py you seems like can't do this. Based on the code: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py?r=411#704

```
if (not path.startswith('/_ah/') or
    any(path.startswith(wl) for wl
        in DISPATCH_AH_URL_PATH_PREFIX_WHITELIST)):
  return True
else:
  logging.warning('Skipping dispatch.yaml rules because %s is not a '
                  'dispatchable path.', path)
  return False
```

any path starting with `/_ah/` is not a dispatchable path.