# GAE Modules and Google Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, routes, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm migrating a GAE application to modules, and have issues with the routing for my `api` module, based on Google Endpoints.

Basically, all my API queries are routed to the default module, while other routing works well

My folder structure is

```
- /gae
-- dispatch.yaml
-- www/
---- www.yaml
---- [www module files]
-- foo/
---- foo.yaml
---- [foo module files]
-- api/api.yaml
---- api.yaml
---- [foo module files]
```

dispatch.yaml

```
application: testapp

dispatch:
  - url: "testapp.appspot.com/"
    module: default
  - url: "*/_ah/spi/*"
    module: api
  - url: "*/_ah/api/*"
    module: api
  - url: "*/foo/*"
    module: foomodule
```

I'm deploying with

```
cd gae
appcfg.py update www/www.yaml upload/upload.yaml api/api.yaml
appcfg.py update_dispatch .
```

I can see 3 instances (one per module) being deployed.

But then:

- queries such as http://testapp.appspot.com/xxx are correctly routed to the default module/instance
- `/foo/xxx ones` are handled by the foomodule
- API requests (`/_ah/spi/xxx`) are going to the default module with a 404.
- Strangely, when starting the app, I can see a  200 OK for `/_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages` in the logs of the `api` instance.

From the logs I also see that:

- The previous logMessage 200 OK comes from `alpha-dot-api-dot-testapp.appspot.com`
- The 404 for the `api` module are from `testapp.appspot.com`
- Yet, the 200 OK for non-default modules are also from ``testapp.appspot.com`

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? Any special routing needed for Google Endpoints when they're used as modules?

Answer (score 1):

As i see the API is the default module, in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Uploading_modules) say "the default module must be uploaded first" also you need put the parameter  "module: default" in the yaml file or not included at all 
Try

```
appcfg.py update  api/api.yaml www/www.yaml upload/upload.yaml #api first
appcfg.py update_dispatch
```